# Variables viewer on Eclipse debugging truncates the string values

Tags: python, eclipse, variables, debugging

I'm debugging Python code and when I try to show the contents of an string variable its showed truncated...

How can show the full contents of a variable debugging Python code with PyDev on Eclipse?

Comment: Unfortunately as this is a Python specific answer---If you are trying to view a certain section of the string you could always use some_string[x:y] to select from the xth to the yth element to view that in the expression tab of the debug environment.

Answer (score 44):

If you right-click on the details pane in either the "Variables" view or the "Expressions" view, there is a `Max Length...` menu option. You can enter a number there to configure the truncation of string output. Keep in mind that the calculated length includes the type identifier at the beginning, so `str: 12345` is actually 10 characters, not 5.

There seems to be a hard limit of 1000 characters, even when entering `0`, which the field description claims means "unlimited," so no matter what you put in, you will never see more than 1000 characters. I don't know if that's a known issue or not; I have not looked into it. For strings or other variables longer than this, I generally use the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module from the standard library and send the string to a log file or stderr.

Comment: I need more than 1000 characters to view because I want to view an XML web response. About using logging its a nice way when debugging your own code but in my case I'm debugging thirty-party libraries to see what is happening and to use logging is annoying.

Comment: Note: the "details pane" is the blank space where the strings are displayed. Maybe obvious for the most...

Comment: it's actually 1024 characters

Comment: For me there is no limit. The Max Value was by default set to 10.000, I set it to 0 (unlimited) and my 25.000 chars string is displaying completely.

Comment: @UmbySlipKnot found a way to OVERCOME THE 1024 character limit! In the Variables view you right-click on the variable and select Change value.

Answer (score 5):

Use interactive commands for printing your big variables and don't rely on variables view. Check how to do it at [aptana pydev debug console](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html).

Answer (score 4):

Found the way around!

At the breakpoint start **PyDev Debug Console** [image]
[image]

and then use python interpreter to get the value

Answer (score 1):

As this was the top hit on Google I should add that if you right-click on the variables pane in debug mode and select 'copy variables' the string value that Eclipse is truncating (along with all other variables) is added *in full* to the system clipboard.

you can then paste it into your favourite text editor to extract the targeted value

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true at least for Eclipse 4.2.1 on Ubuntu. When I right click and "Copy Variable" I still get the truncated output on my clipboard.

Comment: This does work for me (Luna / 4.4.1 on Windows 7). Note that it copies the variable type and name along with the value.