# Observe very long String content in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator, logcat

Since LogCat truncates long strings, I work around this using FileOutputStream to inspect the contents of very long strings.

It works but it forces me to 'adb pull' that file, which is not very convenient, compare to watching it on LogCat.

Is there any other way in Eclipse to watch **very** long strings?

Comment: I think the eclipse debugger can display strings of arbitrary length, can't it?

Comment: @Axarydax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199611/variables-viewer-on-eclipse-debugging-truncates-the-string-values suggests that this is a user-controllable setting. I just found it in the bottom part of the details part of the Variables view. Please post your comment as an answer and will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the record, the answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199611/variables-viewer-on-eclipse-debugging-truncates-the-string-values/3199684#3199684).

Answer (score 7):

when you stop in debug on the variable
do the following and past it to a text file [image: var content copy]

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easier to use the eclipse debugging view.

Set a break point at the line where you call Log.* and run your app in debug mode.
When execution reaches the break point the app will ... yes, it will halt.

In the Variables window you may now browse your data and display whatever you need. Copy and paste it at a safe place as well and don't forget to smile :)

Answer (score 0):

What I do, is in "Variables->Change value".

That will show you a Windows with the full text. Then just Copy&paste to notepad.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void logLargeString(String str) {

    if(str.length() > 3000) {
        Log.i(TAG, str.substring(0, 3000));
        logLargeString(str.substring(3000));
    } else
        Log.i(TAG, str);
    }
}
```