# Printing huge string to Logcat

Tags: android, xml, logcat, stringwriter

What is the best way to print XML-string to the Logcat window? The string I am trying to print out is a actually a StringWriter which contain a lot of data, when I try to print it out the Logcat truncates it and does not print out the whole content (it at least seems like it does not). When I try to print out the length of the StringWriter (`StringWriter.toString().length()`) it turns out to be 500, but as far as I can see the XML-content is longer than that. Is the StringWriter limited to a length of 500?
Or are there anyway I can get Logcat to stop truncating the string and print out the whole content instead?

Comment: I think it is limited, just break the string down to 500 characters each and print it out, I don't think there is really an other way.

Comment: What's the idea behind sending it to logcat instead of for instance, saving it to the SDCard as a text file you could easily access later with all the added benefits of being able to format it/search it using your favourite editor such as Notepad++?

Comment: Check if this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/a/5436686/801437

Something related to debug perspective.

Comment: @MarvinLabs : Seemed easier to just print it to the logcat window. But writing to a file may be the way to go.

Comment: @Araw  Try this it's work for me
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7606118/5488468