# Java: In Eclipse Debug Mode, When using 'Display', Increase Displayable Text?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

In eclipse, when debugging Java, in the display view, there is a cutoff to how much text it will display.

I am inspecting a variable that can contain a lot of text.  Is there a way to increase how much text `display` will show, or otherwise view *all* the contents of a variable during debug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found answer here: [Variables viewer on Eclipse debugging truncates the string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199611/variables-viewer-on-eclipse-debugging-truncates-the-string-values/3199684#3199684)

Changing the `Max Length...` parameter in Variable view *does* increase length in `display` view.