# How to remove the cap on the toString() output in the debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

During debugging, the watch/display/inspect and variables views use toString() to display an objects state. Unfortunately, very long messages are capped. How can I remove or change that limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the bottom window of the Variables tab, right click, and you will see a menu item to set the limit. Set the limit to 0.

Comment: Won't setting the limit to `0` automatically set it to `max` which is `1000`?

Comment: I have not tried it but I think I have seen strings longer than 1000, give it a try. I did see the note in the other post about the limit being 1000, but I'm not sure to which version of Eclipse that applies.

Comment: Didn't  try 0 but changing the value in variables view works for all the other views as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked a similar question for Python, here's the answer:

[Variables viewer on Eclipse debugging truncates the string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199611/variables-viewer-on-eclipse-debugging-truncates-the-string-values)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to increase beyond the apparent 1000-character limit, but you can get the full string if you right-click the variable in the 'Variables' window and choose 'Copy Variables'. Then paste into your favourite text editor.