# Eclipse Debugger doesn't show the value of a long string in whole

Tags: django, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm using Eclipse Juno to debug a Django app. However, a long string gets cropped when inspecting the variables in PyDev's debugger:

[image]

The content area of the variable is scrollable, but the value suddenly stops there with the dots (see picture). Clicking the variable or *watching* it doesn't help. This is not a huge problem, but is there an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

See discussion and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3310341/1314763).  Essentially, work around the limitation by typing the variable name into the debug console and it will print out in full.

Answer (score 0):

You can change maxlength. It is a Integer.